# Not able to configure durable subscriber in JMS with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, jms-topic

I'm using Apache ActiveMQ 5.15.13 and Spring Boot 2.3.1.RELEASE. I'm trying to configure durable subscriber, but I'm not able do do. My application on runtime gives me an error as

```
Cause: setClientID call not supported on proxy for shared Connection. Set the 'clientId' property on the SingleConnectionFactory instead.
```

Below is the complete ActiveMQ setup with Spring Boot.

**JMSConfiguration**

```java
public class JMSConfiguration
{
    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> connectionFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
            DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer)
    {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        // This provides all boot's default to this factory, including the message converter
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        // You could still override some of Boot's default if necessary.
        factory.setPubSubDomain(true);
        
        /* below config to set durable subscriber */
         factory.setClientId("brokerClientId"); 
         factory.setSubscriptionDurable(true);
            
       // factory.setSubscriptionShared(true);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter()
    {
        MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
        converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
        return converter;
    }
}
```

**Receiver Class**

```java
public class Receiver {

private static final String MESSAGE_TOPIC = "message_topic";
private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Receiver.class);

private static AtomicInteger id = new AtomicInteger();

@Autowired
ConfirmationReceiver confirmationReceiver;
    
    @JmsListener(destination = MESSAGE_TOPIC,
            id = "comercial",
            subscription = MESSAGE_TOPIC,
            containerFactory = "connectionFactory")
    public void receiveMessage(Product product, Message message)
    {
        logger.info(" >> Original received message: " + message);
        logger.info(" >> Received product: " + product);
        
        System.out.println("Received " + product);
        
        confirmationReceiver.sendConfirmation(new Confirmation(id.incrementAndGet(), "User " +
                    product.getName() + " received."));
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.jms.pub-sub-domain=true
spring.jms.listener.concurrency=1
spring.jms.listener.max-concurrency=2
spring.jms.listener.acknowledge-mode=auto
spring.jms.listener.auto-startup=true
spring.jms.template.delivery-mode:persistent
spring.jms.template.priority: 100
spring.jms.template.qos-enabled: true
spring.jms.template.receive-timeout: 1000
spring.jms.template.time-to-live: 36000
```

When i try to run application it gives me error as below

```
Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'message_topic' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=1, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: setClientID call not supported on proxy for shared Connection. Set the 'clientId' property on the SingleConnectionFactory instead.
```

My application has standalone producer and consumer. I did try to Google the error but nothing helped.

Answer (score 2):

Late answer. Here is what worked for me.

1. Use SingleConnectionFactory in place of ConnectionFactory
2. Set client-id to SingleConnectionFactory
3. Do not set client-id to factory

```
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> connectionFactory(SingleConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
        // Add this
        connectionFactory.setClientId("your-client-id")
        // Do not do this
        //factory.setClientId("brokerClientId");
```